# I am trying to include a prepared statement within another prepared statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

In this given prepared statement it gets the article title. When it gets the article title it is also supposed to send that variable into another prepared statement which then finds the amount of views on the given article.

```
<table class="table table-colored table-centered table-inverse m-0">
<thead>
<tr>

<th>Title</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Writer</th>
<th>Action</th>
<th>Views</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


<?php
$stmt = $con -> prepare('select tblposts.id as postid,tblposts.PostTitle as title,tblposts.PostUrl as postname, tblcategory.CategoryName as category,tblwritter.Writter as writter from tblposts left join tblcategory on tblcategory.id=tblposts.CategoryId left join tblwritter on tblwritter.WritterId=tblposts.WritterId where tblposts.Is_Active=?');
$cnt=1;
$stmt -> bind_param('i', $cnt);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> store_result();
$stmt -> bind_result($postid,$title,$postname,$category,$writter);
?>

 <tr>
<?php while ($stmt->fetch()){?>
<td><b><?php echo $postname;?></b></td>
<td><?php echo $category?></td>
<td><?php echo $writter?></td>


<td>
<a href="edit-post.php?pid=<?php echo $postid;?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil" style="color: #29b6f6;"></i></a>
    &nbsp;<a href="manage-posts.php?pid=<?php echo$postid;?>&&action=del" onclick="return confirm('Do you reaaly want to delete ?')"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color: #f05050"></i></a>
</td>

<?php
$stmt = $con -> prepare('select COUNT(ip) FROM tblviews WHERE postname = ?');
$stmt -> bind_param('s', $postname);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> store_result();
$stmt -> bind_result($ip);
?>
<?php while ($stmt->fetch()){?>
<td><?php echo $ip ?></td>
<?php } ?>

 </tr>


<?php }?>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

The expected results of this code is to send the postname into the prepared statement that then call the amount of views in any given article.

Comment: I presume you’re getting something other than the expected result, but you didn’t say what your actual result is. It would be helpful  if you could edit your question and add a question. In the meantime, your code left me asking a few questions:  1) why bind parameters,  store result, and bind result? All I’ve ever needed is `prepare($query)` and `execute([$values])`. Much simpler, and less error prone.  2) surely this can be done in one query. But I can’t quite picture the tables as I look at your single line query on my phone...  could you break it into separate lines to make it readable?

Comment: Oops, I forgot mysqli doesn’t pass parameter values in `execute()`.  Good reason to dump it in favor of PDO or write a wrapper for it, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  you’re overwriting `$stmt` inside the loop.

Long answer, with tips:
This can be avoided (or at least be more easily detected) by writing all your php first, and then last of all issuing html (using php only for iteration and variable substitution).

Even better is to put db access and business logic into a separate classes (i.e., models) and have your view ask the model (or controller, depending on your interpretation of MVC) for the data it needs.

I have no way to test it, but you should be able to use a single query:

```
select 
    tblposts.id as postid,
    tblposts.PostTitle as title,
    tblposts.PostUrl as postname,
    tblcategory.CategoryName as category,
    tblwritter.Writter as writter,
    COUNT(tblwritter.ip) as views
from tblposts
    left join tblcategory on tblcategory.id=tblposts.CategoryId 
    left join tblwritter on tblwritter.WritterId=tblposts.WritterId 
    left join tblviews on tblviews.postname = tblposts.PostUrl'
where tblposts.Is_Active=?
group by tblposts.PostUrl, tblposts.id, tblposts.PostTitle, tblCategory.CategoryName, tblwritter.Writter
```

(Note, MySQL may let you get away with only naming tblposts.PostUrl in the group by)

This way, your page can be simplified to something like this:

```
<?php
    // do your query here
?>
<table class="table table-colored table-centered table-inverse m-0">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Writer</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>Views</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php while ($stmt->fetch()): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><b><?= $postname ?></b></td>
      <td><?= $category ?></td>
      <td><?= $writter?></td>
      <td>
        <a href="edit-post.php?pid=<?= $postid?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil" style="color: #29b6f6;"></i></a>
&nbsp;<a href="manage-posts.php?pid=<?=$postid?>&&action=del" onclick="return confirm('Do you reaaly want to delete ?')"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color: #f05050"></i></a>
      </td>
      <td><?= $views ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```